# Can I see all previous notifications in Civilization 6?

Tags: civilization-6

There are two types of notifications: The huge pop-ups that hang until you click them and others like combat and tribal village help that are gone almost instantly. Is there a list of all previous notifications?

Answer (score 3):

According to a quick search, there does not appear to be a log [according to this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/58lzdf/notification_log_in_civ_vi/) and others.

There does appear to be a [workshop mod](https://steamcommunity.com/workshop/filedetails/?id=1459493312) that adds a log for these notifications though. You can install this by subscribing to the mod from its page in Steam.